# Marker cluster isnt functioning

Tags: javascript, html, json

I made google map with markers but i have quite a lot of them so wanted to add marker cluterer but it doesnt seem to work. In the console it says "marker is not defined".

```
var urlApi = "https://api.jcdecaux.com/vls/v1/stations?contract=lyon&apiKey=";


function initMap(){

  //map options
      var options ={
          zoom:13,
          center:{lat:45.7563172, lng:4.827523}
      }

  //new map
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),options);
  //new markers
  $.getJSON(urlApi, function(data) {
      data.forEach(function(item) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position : {
              lat : parseFloat(item.position.lat),  
              lng : parseFloat (item.position.lng)

          },
          map:map
        })
      })
    });
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, marker,
      {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
```

```
    <script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js"></script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initMap"></script>
  <script src="animation-fleche.js"></script>
  <script src="slider.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="map.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You create markers, but you don't save them anywhere. You need to create a Marker array and then pass that in to the MarkerCluster constructor:

```
$.getJSON(urlApi, function(data) {
  const markerArray = data.map(function(item) {
    return new google.maps.Marker({
      position : {
          lat : parseFloat(item.position.lat),  
          lng : parseFloat (item.position.lng)
      });
  });
  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markerArray,
  {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});

});
```